# flask app not running automatically from Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, flask

My simple flask app is not automatically starting when I run in docker, though I have added CMD command correctly. I am able to run flask using python3 /app/app.py manually from container shell. Hence, no issue with code or command

```
FROM     ubuntu:latest
RUN      apt-get update
RUN      apt-get install -y gcc libffi-dev libssl-dev
RUN      apt-get install -y libxml2-dev xmlsec1
RUN      apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev
RUN      pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade pip
RUN      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN      mkdir  /app
WORKDIR  /app
COPY     .  /app
RUN      pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE   5000        
CMD     ["/usr/bin/python3", "/app/app.py"]
```

I run docker container as

```
docker run -it okta  /bin/bash
```

When I log in to docker container and run  "ps -eaf" on Ubuntu shell of container, I do not see flask process running. So my question is why below line did not work in Dockerfile?

```
CMD     ["/usr/bin/python3", "/app/app.py"]
```

Comment: What makes you think that your flask app isn't running? What happens when you start the docker container? And what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: When i start container and logging into Ubuntu container then check  "ps -eaf" in terminal, I see flask app is not running.   Then i start it manually using  python3  /app/app.py     ideally      CMD     ["/usr/bin/python3", "/app/app.py"]   should run your command as soon as you run your container, but that is not happening.

Comment: Please edit your question to show that. Also, what happens when you make a request to the flask server?

Comment: Obviously when no flask server running you will get error from web browser.  I do not need to even look into browser end. My question is why the server is not running in the first place?

Comment: It is still a good idea to double check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running your docker container *and* passing the command **/bin/bash** is overriding the CMD ["/usr/bin/python3", "/app/app.py"] in your Dockerfile.

CMD vs ENTRYPOINT Explained [Here](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint/)

Try changing the last line of your Dockerfile to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3", "/app/app.py"]
```

Don't forget to rebuild your image after changing.

Or... you can omit the /bin/bash from the end of your docker run command and see if your app.py starts up successfully.

Comment: Yes it is working thanks. BTW what magic is done by using ENTRYPOINT  instead of CMD ? Can you please briefly let me know?

Comment: ENTRYPOINT commands are always executed no matter what arguments you pass when you run the container. CMD is designed to be overridden when you run the container with arguments like /bin/bash/. The link I posted probably explains it better. If the answer was useful, please mark as answered so that others can be helped.

Comment: There's no reason to change `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT`.  This will just make it harder to run an alternate command should you need to.  Deleting the `bash` command override from the `docker run` command is enough.